# Inserting records in MVC Application using web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can anyone tell me about how to insert records using web API in MVC Application?

Comment: Can you give more information on the question? Like the use case you are working towards? The best way to update the front end is to use AJAX to get information from your web apis to the webpages ( for updation of records after intial rendering)

Comment: I removed those parts in your question that don't carry meaningful information. But now *you* should add more information! As it is written right now, your question is too broad. You should do some serious research and ask more specifically. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a view with the respective fields.
2. Ajax call

   ```
   $("#btnAdd").click(function () {

       var PersonDetails = {
           "FirstName": $("#FirstName").val(),
           "LastName": $("#LastName").val(),
           "Age": $("#Age").val(),
       };

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'webapi post method address',
           data: JSON.stringify(PersonalDetails),
           contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
           success: function (data, status, xhr) {
               alert("The result is : " + status + ": " + data);
           },
           error: function (xhr) {
               alert(xhr.responseText);
           }
       });
   });
   ```
3. Webapi Controller method

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public IHttpActionResult PostPersonalDetails([FromBody] PersonalDetails personaldetails)
   {
       if (!ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           return BadRequest(ModelState);
       }

       db.PersonalDetails.Add(personaldetails);
       db.SaveChanges();

       return Ok(personaldetails);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G83Xi.png)Hello Tejas,
In webApi, when you add a Web API Controller it adds 5 methods. You will find there is a method commented with
POST api/controller.
In this method you have to write your code to insert records in the database. For example:

```
    // POST api/<controller>
    public void Post([FromUri]Book book)
    {
        db.Books.Add(new Book()
        {
            BookName = book.BookName
        });
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Then to insert a record (here a book for example 'GreatBook') with this api you need to send a POST request as follows:(you can test this in Postman software - pls see screenshot)
http://localhost/Books/api/Books?BookName=GreatBook

Hope this helps - for any additional info pls ask.